# Marker is not appearing in google map

Tags: android, google-maps

Marker Is Not Appearing On My Map. I wrote code inside onMapReady Class But Still it's not appearing can someone help me. I cant figure out the problem. i tried many times.

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener{

private GoogleMap mMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    //Map
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    //Add Marker
    LatLng kilin = new LatLng(33.6518, 73.1566);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(kilin).title("Stop")).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car));

}

}
```

Comment: How about try not to call `setIcon()` ? Still not showing?

Comment: Yes Still Not Appearing.

Comment: Are you sure the marker is not set? Try to zoom out and see if it might be a place where you might not expect it to be

Comment: I Zoomout completly everywhere, i have not see marker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code should work , make sure that the icon is not too small or transparent or something,also call `mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(kilin));` after adding the marker to make sure that you are looking for it in the right place

Comment: This Works, Thank You @Fathi